# bind a kendo grid using knockout js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui

im learning knock ut js and i have to speed up my learning since i have got to create a website,i know kendo ui and know how to use it with jquery but if i want to bind my grid using Knockout js what should i do?i have tried the following but its not working,does not show anything when i run it:

my viewmodel

```
   var viewModel = {
       items: ko.observableArray([
          { id: ko.observable('1'), name: ko.observable('a') },
          { id: ko.observable('2'), name: ko.observable('b') },
          { id: ko.observable('3'), name: ko.observable('b') },
          { id: ko.observable('4'), name: ko.observable('d') }
        ])
    };
```

i bind it like this:

```
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

here is my view:

```
 <div data-bind="kendoGrid:{dataSource:items,colums:[{field:'id()'},{field:'name()'}]}"> </div>
```

am i missing something and is it the right way of binding in knock out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about the name and syntax of parameters?

- `dataSource` should be a object containing `data` (see [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/datasource))
- `colums` should be `columns`

Also, you can see the official connector documentation [here](https://kendo-labs.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html).

Comment: thanks for the comment but changing the name also did not work,does not show anything,has it something to do with im doing it in html file ?

Comment: Can you provide a demo in jsfiddle or elsewhere?